# Google Autocomplete sometimes doesn't fires place_changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have an autocomplete and this event in a service

```
var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_id');

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

      });
```

It works almost everytime and 1 out of 10 times, and my problem is that the event is not fired.

In my controller, I get when the user press Enter, and I trigger the event to prevent this, but even so I have this error.

What can be the reason of this?

**Edit:**

It seems that if I write and press Enter very fast the event is not fired by the autocomplete

Comment: Check these related links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816428/how-to-fire-place-changed-event-for-google-places-auto-complete-on-enter-key and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072844/google-places-autocomplete-place-changed-event-fires-after-form-submission-when